# Beaglebone Black pwm at startup using cron just stays high (python)

Tags: python, cron, beagleboneblack

I am trying to make my Beaglebone Black (BBB) output pwm at startup. The program runs correctly when started from the command line. However when I try to get the program to run at startup (using cron) the output of the pin is just high.

Here is the code I am running:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO    #import GPIO library
import Adafruit_BBIO.PWM as PWM      #import PWM library

#Boost Converter Control
boost_frequency = 1000000            #in Hz, 1000000 = 1MHz
boost_duty_cycle = 50                #in % (0-100)

PWM.start("P8_13", boost_duty_cycle, boost_frequency)
```

I saved this as fes_control.py in /root/exo_code

When I run it from the command line using the following I get correct pwm at the output:

```
python fes_control.py
```

I want to be able to run this at startup.

I typed the following into the command line:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Which opens up a file which I add the following line to at the bottom:

```
@reboot python /root/exo_code/fes_control.py &
```

I then save and exit.

However when I reboot the BBB the output of the pin is just constantly high. I have the same issue at 1kHz pwm frequency. I also tried putting "sudo" in between "@reboot" and "python" in the cron file but that didn't change anything. Any ideas what could be going on?

Edit: I have also tried writing a script to run my python program and placing it in /etc/init.d (like what has been done in this tutorial: http://www.pietervanos.net/knowledge/start-python-script-from-init-d/) and I'm having exactly the same issue as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. Turns out that the code I am running needs some things which weren't initilised when the code was being run at startup. I added a delay of 10 seconds at the start of my python code and now it works perfectly at startup :)

Answer (score 0):

crontab is generally used to specify a time a task will run

Your command is missing the time specifiers

> $nano /etc/crontab

Will show you some examples. Here is mine

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
```

17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly

25 6    * * *   root    test -x
    /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )

47
    6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts
    --report /etc/cron.weekly )

52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
    #

So I think a command like this would work

```
* * * * * root python /root/exo_code/fes_control.py
```